# Kubernetes rancher provisioner security context error

Tags: nixos, kubernetes

I'm trying to implement `local-path` provisioner from Rancher.io in my Kubernetes cluster.
This is a single node `k8s` cluster, installed on NixOS, for test purposes.

I followed the Rancher's procedure:

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/v0.0.24/deploy/local-path-storage.yaml
```

At this time I have no errors, I can confirm that Rancher provisioner is running as expected:

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -n local-path-storage
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
local-path-provisioner-8559f79bcf-gg2rk   1/1     Running   0          5m55s
```

I tried next to run a stateful app project as explained in [their documentation](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/blob/master/README.md), as follow:

```bash
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/master/examples/pvc/pvc.yaml
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/master/examples/pod/pod.yaml
```

Unfortunately the pvc is stuck at *Pending* status, with the following error:

```bash
$ kubectl events pvc --types=Warning
LAST SEEN               TYPE      REASON                OBJECT                                 MESSAGE
3m29s (x5 over 7m14s)   Warning   ProvisioningFailed    PersistentVolumeClaim/wp-pv-claim      failed to provision volume with StorageClass "local-path": failed to create volume pvc-966b701d-9a11-4fa5-bb16-e7c40cb8ca58: Pod "helper-pod-create-pvc-966b701d-9a11-4fa5-bb16-e7c40cb8ca58" is invalid: spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by cluster policy
```

I'm aware that [pod security policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/) is now deprecated.

As I am a very beginner on Kubernetes, as on NixOS, I cannot see where to change the security context, and how to manage that.

For additionnal information, here is my NixOS Kubernetes related config:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
let
  kubeMasterIP = "192.168.100.212";
  kubeMasterHostname = "k8s-nix";
  kubeMasterAPIServerPort = 6443;
in
{
  # resolve master hostname
  networking.extraHosts = "${kubeMasterIP} ${kubeMasterHostname}";

  # Required packages for building cluster
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    cri-o
    podman
    kubernetes
    kubernetes-helm
  ];

  # Kubernetes
  services.kubernetes = {
    roles = ["master" "node"];
    masterAddress = kubeMasterHostname;
    apiserverAddress = "https://${kubeMasterHostname}:${toString kubeMasterAPIServerPort}";
    easyCerts = true;
    apiserver = {
      securePort = kubeMasterAPIServerPort;
      advertiseAddress = kubeMasterIP;
    };

    # use coredns
    addons.dns.enable = true;

    # needed if you use swap
    kubelet.extraOpts = "--fail-swap-on=false";
  };

  environment.shellAliases = {
    k = "kubectl";
  };
}
```